# Powershell Query Performance Counters

Tags: performance, powershell

Is there a better way to list counter properties for a particular process:

```
$pids = get-counter -listset process | get-counter -maxsamples 1 | select -expandproperty countersamples | where {$_.path -like "w3wp"} | select cookedvalue | ForEach {$_.cookedvalue}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this approach? Length of it? You can use WMI or .NET in PowerShell to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMI class "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process" to do this as well:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "Name='w3wp'"
```

This will give you the performance counter data pertaining to w3wp processes.

Comment: The problem that I'm running into is that "working set - private" is not included in WMI. Which is really weird because it's used in Windows 2008 as the default display.

Comment: Weird. I see it on Windows 7: VirtualBytes            : 990130176
VirtualBytesPeak        : 995373056
WorkingSet              : 145563648
WorkingSetPeak          : 150052864
WorkingSetPrivate       : 54353920

Comment: This works! Awesome. For some reason I missed this earlier. It'll be much easier now!